# ImportError: No module named contrib

Tags: django

I get this error while installing Misago the forum. I don't know what's causing since I have Django installed. I did a google search for that python module but didn't find any.

```
C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\Misago-0.5.4>manage.py runserver 192.168.1.6:80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\Misago-0.5.4\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg\django\__init__.py"
, line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg\django\apps\registr
y.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg\django\apps\config.
py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named contrib
```

Comment: post the stack trace please and the exact error

Comment: Just did, I hope this helps

Comment: Could you post your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: There should be. Have you followed [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/)? What's the content of your settings module (most likely a file named `settings.py`)?

Comment: Can you post your settings.py?